# Existence of $\sqrt [n] {a}$ with $a\geq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, radicals

Assum that $a\geq 1$. Let

$S_{a}=\left\{ x\in \mathbb{R} :x^{n}\leq a\right\} $.

Then $S_{a}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, which is nonempty (since $1\in S_{a}$) and bouded above. Define $b=\sup S_{a}$. Note that since $1\in S_{a}$, we have $b\geq 1>0$.

For any $\delta\in \mathbb{R}$, we have

$\left( b+\delta \right) ^{n}=b^{n}+\left( \begin{matrix} n\\ 1\end{matrix} \right) b^{n-1}\delta+\left( \begin{matrix} n\\ 2\end{matrix} \right) b^{n-2}\delta^{2}+\ldots +\delta^{n}$.

Now, suppose $b^{n} < a$. Let us define

$\epsilon :=a-b^{n}$, $M:=\max \left\{ \left( \begin{matrix} n\\ k\end{matrix} \right) b^{n-k}:k=1,2,\ldots ,n\right\} $ and $\delta:=\min \left\{ 1,\dfrac {\epsilon } {nM}\right\} $.

I want to know why $0 < \delta ^{k}\leq \delta$ in the proof.

Comment: When you raise a positive number less-than or equal to one to a positive integer power, it doesn't get larger.

Comment: Because $\delta \leq 1$

Comment: Why $\delta \leq 1$?

Comment: because $\delta=min(1,\epsilon/nM)$

Comment: Why $\dfrac {\epsilon} {nM}\leq 1$ ?

Comment: $\epsilon/(nM)$ may be $>1$, but in that case $\min(1,\epsilon/(nM))=1$.